# Flutter rxdart rx.combainelatest not showing inside the getx controller class?

Tags: flutter

I am making a music player using `getx statemanagement`. When looking to combine streams with `rxdart` not showing `rx.combainelatest` inside the `getx controller` class.

How to use `rxdart` in `getx contoller` class or `statelesswidget` class?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.